# mod_rewrite in .htaccess file for unknown first part of path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rewrite rule to change path slugs to query parameters. It is for a web service, and should only rewrite this rule if the host starts with api. There are two slugs that I am trying to capture and rewrite. The first is optional and is a version (i.e. v1.2) and the second is the service domain (i.e. customers, transactions, etc.).

http://api.domain.com/v2.5/customers should rewrite to ?version=2.5&domain=customers

I also want to support a default version so that

http://api.domain.com/customers should rewrite to ?version=&domain=customers

Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\..*
RewriteRule ^v([\d\.]*)?\/?([^\/]*)$ ?version=$1&domain=$2
```

The first example above works fine, but I can't get the default version path to work. I have tried a ton of different things. I thought starting with ^.*v would help, but it didn't. Anybody know how to make it match when you don't know the starting characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Handle the version-including requests first..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\..*
RewriteRule ^v([\d\.]*)/([^/]*)$ ?version=$1&domain=$2 [L]

# ..then catch requests that don't include a version.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\..*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?version=&domain=$1 [L]
```

It could be done in a single regex, but it's a lot more readable this way.